# Notepad++ Regular expression find and delete a line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to find and delete a line using Notepad++

I need to find lines in this file (UNIX Format) that match the string `'`#RedirectMatch Permanent`'` and delete that line.

Does anyone know how to do this using Notepad++ Find and Replace?

Thanks and Kind Regards,

Answer (score 77):

**Step 1**

- `Search` → `Find` → (goto Tab) `Mark`
- `Find what`: ^Session.*$
- Enable the checkbox `Bookmark line`
- Enable the checkbox `Regular expression` (under `Search Mode`)
- Click `Mark All` (this will find the regex and highlights all the lines and bookmark them)

**Step 2**

- `Search` → `Bookmark` → `Remove Bookmarked Lines`

Comment: Welcome to the site - in future, please wait until **you have an answer** before actually posting an answer. I've removed the non-answer part of your post now.

Answer (score 33):

If it supports standard regex...

```
find:
^.*#RedirectMatch Permanent.*$

replace:
```

Replace with nothing.

Comment: This clears the line (leaving the line with no characters except its newline in it), but doesn't delete it. The answer below deletes the line as well.

Comment: you can get the 'deletes the line as well' by adding "\r?\n" (without the quotes) after the $ - this way the search will match the line *and* the newline (CRLF or LF) afterwards, so when you replace with empty string, the line is deleted.

Comment: What @JamesManning says is something like this   `^.*#RedirectMatch Permanent.*$\r?\n`  and replace with empty. But make sure to check the Regular Expression in Search Mode in the Replace Tab.

Answer (score 22):

Provide the following in the search dialog:

**Find What:** `^$\r\n`
**Replace With:** *(Leave it empty)*

Click <kbd>**Replace All**</kbd>

Comment: Don't forget to change the **Search Mode** (in the search dialog) to *Regular Expression*

Comment: Do note that not all lines end with `\r\n`, sometimes it ends with just `\n`. So a better regex would be `^$\r?\n`

Comment: That doesn't work; it leaves the line empty instead of removing it.

Answer (score 9):

Combining the best from all the answers

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using the "Replace all" functionality, you can delete a line directly by **ending your pattern with**:

- If your file have linux (LF) line ending : `$\n?`
- If your file have windows (CRLF) line ending : `$(\r\n)?`

For instance, in your case :

```
.*#RedirectMatch Permanent.*$\n?
```