# Delete all lines on a file non starting by "07"

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

I need to delete all lines on a file non starting by "07". I already try a lot of regular expressions without success. can someone pleas ehelp me with this?

Comment: Show us the code you have tried. Also, if you are doing this in `bash` or the `shell`, then you should add the tag. We have no idea what language you are using because the tags and code are missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex: remove lines not starting with a digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826311/regex-remove-lines-not-starting-with-a-digit) or [Delete all lines starting with # or ; in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185983/delete-all-lines-starting-with-or-in-notepad)

Comment: @jww: No, the "not" in this question is significant.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I added the not-starting duplicate to the "possible duplicate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is

```
^(?!07).*$
```

using the `g` (global) and `m` (multiline) flags. Search on that and replace with nothing.

[Link with explanation](http://regex101.com/r/yI3cP5):

- The `^` asserts "beginning of line" (because we used the `m` modifier).
- The `(?!07)` means "not starting with `07`". It's called a "negative look-ahead".
- The `.*` means "zero or more of anything".
- The `$` means "end of line" (because we used the `m` modifier).
- The `g` modifier means "globally" (all occurrences).

I haven't used Notepad++, but the docs say it uses PCRE, so the above should work. If it expects you to write the expression and flags all together, that would most likely be:

```
/^(?!07).*$/gm
```

Comment: +1 But to remove _whole lines_, I'd modify the pattern to include an optional EOL too: `^(?!07).*$(?:\r?\n)?`. As-is the pattern above leaves empty lines in the wake of the replacements.

Comment: @ridgerunner: Thanks. As I say, I've never used Notepad++, wasn't sure how it would interpret the end-of-line stuff. Seems to have worked for the OP, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
^(?!07).*
```

and replace with nothing.

You don't need `$` because .* stops at new line.

Comment: ***Not*** starting with 07, the OP said.

Comment: That finds the ones that i want to keep. I want to delete all the ones with non "07". Thanks

Comment: Your edit matches any line that doesn't start with `0` or `7`, not lines not starting with `07`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes. I know now. But, you've answered and I can't edit my answer :(

Answer (score -1):

i think you can use a match like this

```
/^(0[^7]).*/gm
```

in this case it will match for any number but not 7

since [07] will match for 0 or 7 not both

Comment: No, that leaves lines that don't start with a `0`.

Comment: can you give me an example so i can fix it?
/(^0[^7]).*/gm

Comment: @ Sirius: See my answer, it has the correct rex and a complete explanation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, i just asked an example, i made an edit and posted on comments

Comment: @ Sirius: I'm afraid I'm not following. That's okay, I don't need to. :-) If you want to know the correct way to do this, that's posted above. I suggest deleting this answer as it's incorrect.

Comment: i just asked an example of how it wouldnt match, i didnt ask for the correct way, you can suggest as many time as you want, instead of downvoting the answer... i dont care

Comment: @ Sirius: There's no reason to be rude. I simply misunderstood your question. Here's an example of a line that would be deleted incorrectly: `0mumble`. As for the downvote, two lessons you need to learn **early** if you're going to be happy contributing on SO: 1. People downvote without commenting, and comment without downvoting. If you assume you know who downvoted something, you will be wrong *dramatically* more often than right. 2. Downvotes are not personal. They're quality control. An answer that is incorrect attracts downvotes, that's what they're for.